Topics/Books/Course Recommendation for Measure theory
I am a beginner in von-Neumann Algebras and Operator Algebras. I have seen that specific some reasoning (like spectral theorem, commutative von-Neumann algebra) in these subjects involves measure theoretic arguments. I have a very basic training in measure theory. Can you kindly help me with any material or mention me specific topics from measure theory that I should cover (keep in mind) to learn Operator algebras and von-Neumann algebras?
I do not want to get lost in stuffs like sigma algebra, outer measure, non-measurable sets, Riemann-Lebesgue integral.
